# MATLAB 2015b (academic version) connector error when starting simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Whenever I try to run a simulink(.slx)-file I get this errors in my MATLAB command window:

```
Error using connector.ensureServiceOn
Error starting MATLAB Connector. Please check that port 31515 is available.

Error in slmsgviewer

Error in slmsgviewer/PersistentInstance

Error in slmsgviewer.processRecord

Error in slsfnagctlr

Error in slsfnagctlr

Error in slsfnagctlr

Error in slsfnagctlr
```

The simulink file does open but when I try to run, it just says "ready" without doing anything.

The solution that I found from people suffering the same problem was to add a new environment variable:
variable name: "JAVA_TOOL_OPTION"
variable Value: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

After adding this environment variable and restarting I tried it again but I got the same error.

I also tried "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" and "_JAVA_OPTIONS" with the same value but nothing seems to work.

Is there another way to get rid of these errors?

Comment: Does simulink work when you start from a blank project? If it does the issue may be with components not supported by your version.

Comment: @xvan  
When I start a blank project, I get this error:
`Warning: An error occurred trying to load the Simulink HMI engine. Possible reasons include pressing Ctrl+C or running MATLAB with
the -nojvm option. Close and re-open any open any Simulink models to assure proper functioning.  For proper functioning of Simulink
HMI and the Simulation Data Inspector, the JVM is required. 
> In slxPackager/partDefHmi  
In slxPackager/registerHandler  
In slxPackager/executeLoadCallbacks  
In slprivate (line 11)  
In load_system (line 21)  
In libbrowse2 (line 21)`

Answer (score 0):

try to install jdk-7u79-windows-x64, it solved my problem!

Comment: I already had it, maybe a different version so I (re)installed jdk-7u79-windows-x64 but it didn't solve my problem.